# How can my JavaScript assert library return a pass?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, assert

I am working on a custom Javascript assert library, primarily for use in test runners like Mocha.

The library works fine when the test fails, by throwing an Error. However, I can't figure out how to make the library return a "pass", when there's no Error to throw.

I have tried reading through the source of other libraries like Should and Chai, but haven't been able to locate this aspect.

Here is my assert library, `my-assert-lib.js`:

```
module.exports = function(input){
    var methods = {
        compare: function(comparison){
            if(input != comparison){
                throw new Error("The comparison string didn't match")
            }
            else{
                return
            }
        }

    }
    return methods
}
```

Here is my `test.js`, which I'm executing with Mocha:

```
var myAssertLib = require("./my-assert-lib.js")("correct");

describe("The comparison string", function(){
    it('should match the library input', function(doc) {
        myAssertLib.compare("incorrect")
    });

    it('should match the library input', function(doc) {
        myAssertLib.compare("correct")
    });
})
```

I get these results:

```
  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1) The comparison string
       should match the library input:
     Error: The comparison string didn't match
      at Object.compare (my-assert-lib.js:5:23)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:10:21)

  2) The comparison string
       should match the library input:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

The first test exits immediately, as it should. However, the second test times out. What does `my-assert-lib.js` need to do when there's nothing to throw and the test runner should continue?

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using the built-in assert method? https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#

Comment: Do you mean using the built-in assert method within my tests directly, or within my library? I'm creating my own library because I have some pretty specific needs that do not appear to be covered by commonly available libraries. I have removed all of those special bits from the question since I don't think they're relevant here. If you're suggesting using built-in assert in my library, could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why, but mocha is expecting you to call the `done` function.

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Doing so yields one pass and one fail, as expected.

```
describe("The comparison string", function(){
    it('should match the library input', function(done) {
        myAssertLib.compare("incorrect")
        done()
    })
    it('should match the library input', function(done) {
        myAssertLib.compare("correct")
        done()
    })
})

>   The comparison string
>     1) should match the library input
>     ✓ should match the library input
> 
> 
>   1 passing (14ms)   1 failing
> 
>   1) The comparison string
>        should match the library input:
>      Error: The comparison string didn't match
>       at Object.compare (assertLib.js:7:23)
>       at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:7:21)
```

Comment: Ah! Looks like I accidentally passed an argument to the test function, which was being interpreted as a callback — that I never called. Removing it fixed the issue. Thank you!